# Rails and serving from subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

For a particular user acceptance environment, I need my Rails 4.2.5 app to be accessed at a subdirectory. Looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root, I created a file in initializers which looks like:

```
MyApp::Application.config.relative_url_root = '/myapp'
```

With this change, I can access the app in the user acceptance environment at `/myapp`. However, my redirects don't work as expected. For example, when I create a new record in `myapp`, I have code which looks like:

```
def create
  @my_record = MyRecord.new(args)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @my_record.save
      format.html { redirect_to @my_record, notice: 'Record successfully created' }
```

I would have expected this to get redirected to `/myapp/hash_of_newly_created_record`. However, it redirects to `/hash_of_newly_created_record`.

Am I missing anything in my configuration for serving the app from a sub-directory. Do I require any additional configuration to ensure that `redirect_to` works in all environments?

Hope you can help,

Sean